# Installing any version of Linux on Windows surface rt

Tags: linux, surface

I have an old Windows surface rt, I believe second generation.  It has 16 gb of storage and 2gb of ram.  Is it possible to install a version of Linux on it?  I have read conflicting reports based on the storage not being a bookable device.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: NO. There is no solution yet. However, I came across this forum and found that some interesting developments are going on related to it.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-8-rt/rt-development